# Is it correct to say that Square Root of 0.9 is 0.9 itself

Tags: square-numbers

When I calculate Square Root of 0.9, it comes around 0.9486832980505138.
Though I have heard people occasionally saying that the square root of 0.9 is 0.9 itself.
Would it be correct to make a statement like this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you round the result to one decimal only, that statement is not wrong. But one should at least indicate the rounding (e.g., say that the square root of $0.9$ is *approximately* $0.9$)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, it makes sense.

Comment: Not the best choice of rounding, if you ask me, since $0.9^2\approx 0.8$...

Comment: Note that "square root of $0.9$ is $0.9$" implies that the square of $0.9$ is also $0.9$, while $0.9^2 = 0.81$, which is closer to $0.8$. So, one should be very accurate with rounding here.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli No, the other way around silly

Comment: Anyone know how to say "rounded to one digit" in math form?  Like some O notation or something?

Comment: @SimpleArt I know it is the other way around. I'm just saying that it behaves badly when you backtrack, due to the fact that $1-\alpha\approx 0.1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is that you rounded your answer to $0.9$

But even if you did round, it would be incorrect to say $\sqrt{0.9}=0.9$

The correct statement is that the square root of $0.9$ is approxiamately $0.9$

$$\sqrt{0.9}\approx0.9$$

Comment: That is correct! Very nice answer!